# Getting an error from the exe file of Windows Service

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, service, windows-services

I wrote a Windows Service in Visual Studio 2008 (c#)
How do I create an *.exe file of my Windows Service?

I am trying to use [This guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) but can't make it work.

With the help from [todda.speot.is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242520/todda-speot-is) found the exe file. now when I'm trying to open it, I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify, as a Windows service is an .EXE to start with! Do you mean that you'd like it also to run as a standalone program?

Comment: What's the specific problem you had with that guide? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ Jeremy McGee - Now it is just a c# application (Windows Service project).... I need to Install it somehow, and make it an exe file (It's my first windows service so I'm a bit confused)

Comment: @ Polynominal - I created the installers (successfully I think), but when I need to pick my serviceInstaller in the project's Properties window, I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of a Windows Service project is an `.exe`. Get is out of the `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` folder.

Comment: Thanks! when I click on the exe file I get the error: Windows service start failure - cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. a windows service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windws Dervices Administrative tool or the NET START command.

Comment: You wanted an `.exe`, you got a `.exe`. If you want something else, you need to ask in your question. An `.exe` of what?

Comment: If you're trying to make an installer for your service you probably want to re-read the instructions in your linked article. Note that the output of that will probably be a `.msi` and not a `.exe`

Comment: I found another guide that worked fine. Thanks a lot for the help! =)